# Taxonomy Term showing strange text

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Having taxonamy term issues - as glossary terms showing with text below the text  saying "There is currently no content classified with this term."

does anyone know how to remove or hide the statement mentioned?

Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

override default with the "taxonomy/term/%" views

or

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if(isset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['no_content'])) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['no_content']);
  }
}
```